# Spring Boot Thymeleaf fragments from controllers instead of view beans

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've read the documentation, but it's still a bit confusing.
Let's say I have a template called index.html. Inside index.html I want to update a container tag with a fragment based on a request.
Here's my fragment called searchResult.html:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
    <div th:fragment="searchResult">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I want this fragment to be shown inside a particular tag inside index.html how do I do this from the controller?

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String showIndex(){
 return "index";
}
@RequestMapping("/search")
public String search(){
 return "index :: searchResult";
}
```

At showIndex() I want to show everything except for the fragment.
During a get request mapped to search() I want to return the entire index including the fragment. What should my template and controller look like?

Template:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>Usual content shown all the time</div>
<div id="searchResult">
 THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE FRAGMENT TO BE INJECTED
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Or should I just add the result from a search to the model and refresh index in which I instead always have markup for it with a conditional utility class like th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty()}" ?

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, Thymeleaf is built upon a simple request/response workflow.  When you start adding controllers like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/search")
public String search(){
  return "index :: searchResult";
}
```

you have to call that controller yourself with javascript/ajax and use some form of dom manipulation to replace the element.  There is no mechanism with which thymeleaf will automatically update fragments based on changes and fragments are mainly intended to simplify reuse of the same html on multiple pages rather than dynamically updating a page without a page refresh.

Your comment is the way to go, if you want to do it the thymeleaf way.